# Converting double to int

Tags: java, int, double

Quick question, What is the best way to convert an primitive data type double to a primitive data type int. Currently I am using the following code but it seems to be a lot of methods to do a simple task.

```
double i = 2.0;
int i2 = Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(i));
```

Comment: `(int)yourDoubleVariable` may work.

Comment: How would you define 'best'?

Comment: It doesn't produce an error int Netbeans so I hope that means it will work. But I can't test it yet.

Answer (score 6):

just cast double to  (int)

```
double i = 2.0;
int i2 =  (int) i;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either cast the double to an int:

```
double i = 2.0
int i2 = (int) i;
```

or, you could round the number to the nearest whole number, then cast it to an int, just in case you would like to round:

```
double i = 2.2
int i2 = (int) Math.round(i);
```

or, you could use

```
double i = 2.0
int i2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i));
```

About best, though, the **first** option would be best for the least code, and the **second** would be better if you would like to get the closest integer to the double.

Comment: You also need to cast the second one...

Comment: @Dukeling I actually thought that to, so I tried using `int i = Math.round(2.2)` in eclipse and it turns out you don't need to cast it.

Comment: Because in that case it treats `2.2` as a `float`. Try it with the `double` declaration as in your answer.

Comment: @Dukeling Ah, when rounding a `float` you will get an `int`, and when rounding a `double` you will get a `long`. Updated answer.

Comment: An alternative is to use a float (2.2f), which will work without the need to cast.

Comment: @Makoto True, yet this would not work if you're doing something like `double d = 2.2;`, `int i = Math.round(d);`, due to the fact that you can't use float literal in a variable (Even though I think you should be able to do `Math.round((d)f);`.

Comment: The 3rd suggestion throws a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 1):

You can turn any object from one compatible type to another by using 'type-casting'. You use this syntax:

```
double i = 2.0;
int i2 =  (int) i;
```

Notice how I just put `(int)` before the variable `i`? This basically says 'hey, try to make i an int, if you can'. Since java can easily convert a float to an int, it will.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `Math.floor()`.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        double i = 2.9;

        System.out.println((int)(i));
        System.out.println((int)Math.floor(i));
        System.out.println((int)(-i));
        System.out.println((int)Math.floor(-i));        
    }
}
```

output:

```
2
2
-2
-3
```